# How to force Chrome to open all links in the current tab?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

How can I force Chrome to open all links in the current tab?

Does anyone know if there is an extension for that?  It's very annoying that every time I click on links they are be opened in new tabs.

I want it acting like Safari does – just opening the links in the current tab unless I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> when clicking the links.

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension called [OpenHere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panlnaemgbbdbmppblcdgjjamkopjcak) that will do this. It will add the option in the right click context menu **`Open in This Window`**. Just right clcik on the link you want to open in the same tab.

**Edit in response to comment:**

You can do it with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You have need to download it and install it on your PC. After that just copy the code below and save it with a `.ahk` extension.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
#IfWinActive, - Google Chrome$
!RButton::  
    !LButton::  
        KeyWait, Alt  
        Click, Right  
        SendInput, e  
        ControlFocus, Chrome_OmniboxView1  
        SendInput, ^a{Backspace}  
        SendInput, ^v{Enter}   
        return
#IfWinActive
```

Now when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LClick</kbd>, it will copy the link to the clipboard and past it in the address bar of Chrome. Just press the button and click and release with the click and the link will open in the same tab.

Comment: Thanks for helping Avirk! but I am actually looking for a method that can change Chrome's behavior when I left click on the links, it will show up in the current tab instead of opening in a new tab. Just like Safari does.

Comment: @georgechang check out the updated answer. However Chrome works much differently form the Safari so the LClick will not work directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. But I am using Mac, so I think it is a hopeless case to me...... have to switch back to Safari i think.....

Answer (score 2):

If autohotkey is is the way you want to go, there's a much simpler way of doing it:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
    !LButton::
        Send, ^{LButton}
        Send, ^{F4}
    return
#IfWinActive
```

This just ctrl-clicks wherever the mouse is and then closes the current tab when you alt-click anywhere on a chrome tab. And since it isnt sophisticated enough to activate ONLY when clicking on a link, you could also use it as a shortcut to close the current tab by alt-clicking anywhere on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[Open link in same tab, pop-up as tab](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/open-link-in-same-tab-pop/jbhbalpncehdfjnfcmmimecdhalmjjem)** extension.

Description:

> Forces Chrome to open new tabs instead of pop-up windows and/or links in the same tab by default instead of new or background tab.
>
> Converts popups to tabs